# Converting R command line arguments into integer vectors

Tags: r, rscript

I want to read command line arguments in `R` through `Rscript` and use the values stored in them for some integer operations. By default, the command line arguments are imported as characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
arg <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
x = as.vector(arg[1])
class(x)
x
y = as.vector(arg[2])
class(y)
y
cor.test(x,y)
```

This is the output of this script:

```
$ Rscript Correlation.R 3,3,2 4,8,6
[1] "character"
[1] "3,3,2"
[1] "character"
[1] "4,8,6"
Error in cor.test.default(x, y) : 'x' must be a numeric vector
Calls: cor.test -> cor.test.default
Execution halted
```

How can I convert x and y to numeric vectors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

can you try a strsplit, and as.integer() or as.numeric() ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
arg <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
x = as.integer(strsplit(arg[1], ",")[[1]])
class(x)
x
y = as.integer(strsplit(arg[2], ",")[[1]])
class(y)
y
cor.test(x,y)
```

Answer (score 3):

Given `x <- "3,3,2"`

You can obviously split the character on the `,` criterion and cast it to `numeric`.

```
as.numeric(strsplit(x,",")[[1]])
```

Another approach would be to evaluate this string expression as if it was part of an instruction. I wouldn't call this solution more clever in this situation, but it is still worth mentioning.

```
eval(parse(text=paste("c(",x,")",sep="")))
```